# Screen script doesn't work

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I've created the following bash script, which restarts my parse server:

```
pkill screen
screen
cd /datadrive/parse-server-example/
sudo npm start
```

The thing is, it seems that the script doesn't execute the last 2 commands. When the script is executed, it reaches the second command (`screen`) and then I have to manually run the 2 remaining commands.

Any idea why's that?

PS: I've turned off the copyright notice at startup

Comment: Must the `screen` command successfully run to run the next commands? If not then perhaps a `;`or `||` between them might help

Comment: Yes it's necessary!

Comment: Then perhaps `screen` isn't completed to have the other two run or is it?

Comment: That is NOT how you run commands in screen.  Your script is waiting for screen to exit. `screen -d -m command_to_run_in_screen`

Comment: Also you likely should configure npm rather than using the cd command. I am not sure why you need the cd command, see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/npm.1.html

Comment: @Panther like `screen -d -m  sudo npm start /datadrive/parse-server-example/`?

Comment: Something like that. Why are you running the cd command? You may need quotes

Comment: Because the node module is placed there

Comment: I am not familiar with npm modules. See https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally or ask a new question